# neighbourhood concept-how come $[0,1]^2$ is not a neighbourhood of $(1,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Below is the capture from lecture slides

$frac{}{}$[image]

I know what the neighbourhood definition is, and it seems to me $[0,1]^2$ is the neighbourhood of $(1,1)$ and $(0,\frac{1}{2})$

**Further edited**

Thank you so much for your reply. I regard $[0,1]^2$ as a unit square if I do not get it wrong, those examples are at the boundary of the set. I just noticed **closed set is not a neighbourhood of its end-point** This bugs me!!

According to this, I believe the set is not the neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ as well, but **Isn't  $[0,\frac{1}{2})$ open in $[0,1]$?** This is analogy that I rely on to make the claim.

Comment: That looks like a bad definition of "neighborhood" to me. A neighborhood $N$ of a point $p$ should contain an open set $U\subseteq N$ such that $p\in U$. Some authors require neighborhoods to be themselves open.

Comment: The slides give an **informal** definition of the term "neighborhood," but the key point is the word "surround:" when we surround something, we surround it on all sides. The point $(1,1)$ is the top-right corner of the square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$. It is not surrounded by that square, since e.g. if we "go up" from $(1,1)$ we leave the square immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the slide says that a neighborhood should surround the point, it means that there is a disk of positive radius centered at the point that is included in the neighborhood. $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ is not a neighborhood of $(1,1)$ because you can escape starting from $(1,1)$ following the diagonal $(t,t)$, $t > 1$ without meeting $[0,1]\times [0,1]$.

Note that we are talking of neighborhoods of points *in the plane*. The notion of open sets and neighborhood are relative to the space the point belongs to.

A subset is open or not in a given set. For example, $[0,1/2)$ is an open subset of $[0,1]$ but not an open subset of ${\bf R}$.

In the slides, the notion of neighborhood and open sets are relative to the plane itself. If instead of the plane, you consider the space $[0,1]\times [0,1]$, then the subset $(1/2,1] \times (1/2,1]$ is a neighborhood of the point $(1,1)$ in the square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I've just edited the question.